# Better chances of getting in if university would like to review my incomplete application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application

I had recently applied to a somewhat niche Master's program (~100 applicants for ~20 places per year, according to the University's statistics) at a top university (top 5 QS in various disciplines)¹.

One of the reasons I hadn't considered this program seriously is because some of my professors limited the number of letters they could write. Given this constraint, I wanted to optimize my chances of getting an admit by applying to other less-competitive programs which also didn't require 3 recommendations while still being a good fit. So, I just filled random information just so I could submit².

A few days later, as expected, I got an email stating that my application would not be assessed. However, I now received another email stating that the admissions committee would like to review my application if the references are received.

My question is (assuming I'm allowed to edit my references):
Does the fact that the committee would still like to review my incomplete application mean that I have a good chance of getting in? i.e. I would like to know if it is worth it to "spend" 3 recommendation letters on this program now?

---

¹ I mention the ranking only to provide context while keeping the question general.
² I know it was pointless, but I had to "submit" because of reasons I cannot disclose. I thought that since it was incomplete, the admissions committee wouldn't need to waste any time on it.

Comment: This is not really a question that can be answered here, as it depends on individual factors. I think this is a decision that you have to make: how much would like to get into this program? Is it worth to YOU to spent the recommendation letters? This might also be dependent if you are already accepted somewhere else.

Comment: To me it seems to signify only that they don't have enough obviously qualified candidates and seek to expand the pool. Better than nothing, but only they can say.

Comment: Now I'm curious how big people think "niche" is.